# ¿Como puedo meter contenido en una nueva ventana?

Tags: javascript, funciones, ventana, template-strings

me gustaria meter el contenido de htmlText en una nueva ventana, aqui esta mi codigo y lo que he querido introducir:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const boton = document.querySelector("#boton_procesar");
const array = document.querySelector("#array");
let htmlText = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head></head>

            <body>
                <p>Numero de palabras: ${textarea.value.split(" ").length}</p>
                <p>Primera palabra: ${textarea.value.split(" ")[0]}</p>
                <p>Ultima palabra: ${textarea.value.split(" ")[textarea.value.split(" ").length-1]}</p>
                <p>Al revez: ${textarea.value.split(" ").reverse()}</p>
                <p>Ordenadas alfabeticamente: ${textarea.value.split(" ").sort()}</p>
                <p>Ordenadas alfabeticamente al revez: ${textarea.value.split(" ").sort().reverse()}
            </body>
        </html>
    `


function textAreaLenght () {
    return textarea.value.trim().length;
}

function enviarString () {
    let windowArray = window.open('./array.html', 'Procesamiento de Array', "width=600, height=600");
    if(windowArray) {
        windowArray.document.write(htmlText);
    }
}

textarea.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    if (textAreaLenght() > 0 && textarea.value !== '' &&event.keyCode === 13) {
        enviarString();
    }
});

boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (textAreaLenght() > 0 && textarea.value !== '') {
        enviarString();
    }
});
```

Sin embargo al poner el contenido dentro de la nueva ventana solo me aparece dentro de esta solo me aparece esto:

Numero de palabras: 1

Primera palabra:

Ultima palabra:

Al revez:

Ordenadas alfabeticamente:

Ordenadas alfabeticamente al revez:

No estan los datos de las variables que quiero mostrar y creo que se que es por que las variables no se generan en la nueva ventana o algo por el estilo, como puedo hacer que las variables aparezcan en la nueva ventana y se muestre el contenido de ellas? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `htmlText` ponla dentro de tu método `enviarString`

```
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const boton = document.querySelector("#boton_procesar");
const array = document.querySelector("#array");


function textAreaLenght () {
    return textarea.value.trim().length;
}

function enviarString () {
    let htmlText = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head></head>

            <body>
                <p>Numero de palabras: ${textarea.value.split(" ").length}</p>
                <p>Primera palabra: ${textarea.value.split(" ")[0]}</p>
                <p>Ultima palabra: ${textarea.value.split(" ")[textarea.value.split(" ").length-1]}</p>
                <p>Al revez: ${textarea.value.split(" ").reverse()}</p>
                <p>Ordenadas alfabeticamente: ${textarea.value.split(" ").sort()}</p>
                <p>Ordenadas alfabeticamente al revez: ${textarea.value.split(" ").sort().reverse()}
           </body>
        </html>
    `
    let windowArray = window.open('./array.html', 'Procesamiento de Array', "width=600, height=600");
    if(windowArray) {
        windowArray.document.write(htmlText);
    }
}

textarea.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    if (textAreaLenght() > 0 && textarea.value !== '' &&event.keyCode === 13) {
        enviarString();
    }
});

boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (textAreaLenght() > 0 && textarea.value !== '') {
        enviarString();
    }
});
```